# Dell Inspiron N7110 start up issue after the update Windows 10 anniversary?

Tags: windows-10, boot, dell-inspiron

I have an issue that I have been googled about bootup on my laptop. I have a laptop from DELL Inspiron N7110 that I bought from QVC a few years ago. It still runs good and have had Windows 7 since then. I update the new version Windows 10 last spring of this year without any problem. So when Microsoft released their Windows 10 anniversary update deployed last September 29, 2016, my DELL laptop had some bootup issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...The problem was when you turn it on and I use my Phone to capture the problem and it said "Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller Series v1.23. PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable. PXE-M0F.  Here is what I do, I went to DELL online and then ran Diagnotics test for that and it said No Network cable was detected. Connect your network cable. I google to try and find out more information.
I went to this site, https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/a-common-and-easy-way-to-access-device-manager-in-windows/ and check mine and it showed for that network card and looked fine. No error.
I then open "Driver Easy" to run some testes and it detected that network card driver and install it.

I then shutdown a couple of time and that solved the problem !! It took me a few months to figure it out.

I thought I would share with this to anyone.